# Calling Native APIs from Managed Code

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6

I am developing a Windows Mobile application using WM6 SDK. The application is a Managed code (using C#) & I would like to know the steps to be taken in order to call native functions.

Thanks for the help,
 Abdel Olakara

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.pinvoke.net/

That should do it.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this site.. was able to get details of what I need.

Answer (score -1):

You need to first declare the native APIs as static extern using [DLLImport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.aspx)  and then use them like normal methods. Example:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
    internal static extern IntPtr SetTimer(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr nIDEvent, int uElapse, IntPtr lpTimerFunc);
```

Comment: A good example - but would have been better if it was designed for Windows Mobile. Unlike the desktop most APIs will be found within a single dll called coredll.dll, so the above example will actually throw an exception on a Windows Mobile device stating user32.dll can not be found.